# Full electron propagator in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, feynman

I want to draw a diagram as shown below in overleaf,
please help me[image]

Comment: Sure, what have you done so far? Could you post a minimal working example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, to give you a start, have a look at the [`tikz-feynman`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-feynman)-package.

The following code should get you started:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\tikzfeynmanset{
    every blob={
        draw=black,
        pattern color=black
    },
}

\feynmandiagram[horizontal=a to b] {a -- [fermion] b [blob],};

\end{document}
```

[image: tikz-feynman]